# How to use Functional Programming on App development

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I've been reading and playing with Functional Programming (FP) and I really like it's concepts, but I'm not sure how to apply them for most of my applications.

I'll be more specific, let's talk about iOS apps. I do see how to use some of the concept like immutable data structures and higher order functions, but not how to work with only/mostly pure functions - avoiding side effects - which seems to be the main part of FP.

I feel like most of the app is about coordinating input calls, displaying data, saving data, making network requests, navigating from one screen to another, animations.

All those would be impure functions on FP:

- Coordinating input: a button tap, a notification, a server socket push, for all those I have to decide what to call, where to observe them, etc.
- Displaying data: reads from a local database or from a server (side effect).
- Saving data: same as above (but writing).
- Making network requests: obvious, so I'll just give an example here - retrieving list images from Instagram.
- Navigating: that's basically presenting View Controllers, which is a side effect.
- Animations: changing something on the screen, side effect.

There are very few places in which I have to process data and those consist almost always of retrieving some Struct's from the database and concatenating the multiple information into another Struct that will be used by the View Controller (that's like 5 lines... assuming you need 5 properties to be displayed in the view). Sure, you might need to do some processing like converting `money: Int = 20 to moneyString: String = "US$\(money).00"`, but that's it.

I feel like I'm failing to implement FP in my app development cycle. Can anyone clarify how I can achieve that? Maybe with examples.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** right now, following the [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) idea, I have something like this as my architecture:

[image]

Inputs can come from the `View`, as a button click, they go to the `ViewController` who decides which `Interactor` to call. That `Interactor` will access the necessary `Gateway`s to get some data and transform it into presentable data that will be passed to the `Presenter` (in the form of a delegate). Finally the `Presenter` will update the `View` to display the new data.

Additionally, the input can come from `External` sources, like the server telling you some data was updated and you have to refresh the `View`. That goes to the `Interactor` (in the form of observer) which will follow the rest of the chain as in the previous example.

The only FP part is transformaing the `Gateway`'s data into presentable data. All the rest has side effects. I feel like I'm doing something wrong and maybe some of that code should be organized differently so that more code can be moved to pure functions.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @dfri I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @Eric D I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @JAL I updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside FP for a moment, the challenge with multi-user or time dependent models is that the end-user in front of the program is not the only source of control events.

To keep the dependencies clean, we should view external triggers as an form of user input (unsolicited as it may be) and process them through the same paths.

If the end user had somehow been telepathically informed that new data was available, he could have pressed a button to have the program get it.  Then no backward control flow would ever be needed (such as push notifications).

In that perfect world, the user's action to get the data would have first been captured at the View level and then carried down the layers.

This tells us that the notifications should be handled by the view controller or, better yet by a view component designed to receive them.  Such notifications however would not contain any data except perhaps some indication of which part of the model have been invalidated.

Back to FP, this is of course a gigantic side effect if you consider that all function calls thereafter will return potentially different results.  BUT...

In mathematics, if you define a function that gives you distance traveled at a given speed but don't supply the time parameter, you're not victim of a side effect, you merely forgot to provide an input value.

So, if we consider that all software layers are pure functions but that time is an implicit parameter given with the initial input, you can validate that your program conforms to FP by checking that repeated calls, in any order, to functions of the system when time is frozen should always return the same results.

If databases could keep a 100% complete set of snapshots of their states at any given time it would be possible to validate pure FP conformance of applications by freezing time or making it a parameter.

Back in the real world now, such a design is often impractical for performance reasons.  It would pretty much preclude any form of caching.

Still, I would suggest you try to categorize notifications as unsolicited user input in your design. I believe it may help solve some of the conundrums.

Comment: So basically instead of having the `Interactor` observe the notifications, my `ViewController` (or another `Controller` in the middle of those 2) would, correct? If so, that means my `Interactor` will only have one source of input (some `execute` method that would be called), removing the observing from it (although that won't make much difference, since I was only calling the same `execute` method when a notification arrives, so the `execute` method stays the same). But still the problem remains, my `Interactor` is still accessing the database.

Comment: I'm not sure if you consider the presenter to be part of the VC or Model but it is in an uncomfortable position there.  I normally place data remodelling in the model layer so that the VC can have a very naive view of the universe where everything always exists and the only state it maintains is the minimum required to know where the user is at in that universe.   If your data is on a distant server, some performance considerations might creep in, but you should be able to create an abstraction of the data that hides all fetching and caching to the VC and keep states to a minimum in all layers

Comment: I only add a presenter if my VC starts getting too big. But imagine a UITableViewController, where do you keep the array with the data?

Answer (score 1):

There should always be more than one tool in your toolbox.  FP is a great approach and a discipline that most people should have for pieces of the program where it applies (e.g. presenting the model on the views through the view controllers in MVVC).

Attempting to use FP on everything in an application is probably not a worthwhile endeavour.   As soon as you're going to persist data or manage the passage of time, you'll have to deal with states.   Even the  "restful" services (which are conceptually good candidates for an FP approach) will not be pure FP and have some state dependency.  This is not because they are bad FP implementations but because it is their purpose to manage externally persisted states.  You could spin it to view stored data as "the input" but from either side of the service the other side will still be a side effect (except for read-only operations).

If you embrase the fact that MVVC is responsible for managing state transition, and allow for a non-FP relationship between its components, it becomes easier to implement smaller scale FP paradigm to each of them.

For example, your view controllers should not have any variables that duplicate or maintain transformed versions of any data in the model.  The use of delegates between MVVC components does break the FP rules in some cases but within the scope of functionality of a view controller, those are inputs (not states).   By planning (and drawing) an interaction diagram before you start coding , you'll be able to better isolate concerns and not get into dead ends that will break FP within your components.

Within the model itself, computed properties can go a long way in ensuring that you abide by FP.

In any case, if you never use the var statement (this is going to be a challenge in some places), you're likely to end up with FP conforming code.

Comment: How would I remove the duplicated transformed data in a UITableViewController? I need an array there to be used in my data source methods.

Comment: I've updated my question to add a more concrete example of my architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming is good for tackling specific programming issues. Where FP excels is in concurrent/parallel programming; if you have read any of the articles written by Herb Sutter on the concurrent programming, you begin to see the overlap in good concurrent/parallel programming and functional design.

For an application, as Alain had said, you do have to work with state. You can apply FP design patterns around how state is modified, but regardless, you do have to modify state at one point or another, which is as you discovered, not aligned with pure FP.

FP is a tool in your tool chest of programming patterns, but it is not the only tool.

Comment: I'm ok having state in my view layer (Views and ViewControllers), but it seems like most of my application is just passing information around, so my problem is with side effects, as in reading from a database. Am I not splitting some part of my code that should no go on the same place as my ViewController?

Comment: I've updated my question to add a more concrete example of my architecture.